# How to expand a partition into a block of free space that is not adjacent to it?

Tags: partition, cfdisk

[image: Screenshot of cfdisk]
In the above situation, how would I go about expanding `/dev/sda6` to take up the highlighted free space?

Comment: What kind of filesystem? It would be easy if you were using LVM... otherwise you can only move partitions around (with gparted or similar), which is annoying, and somewhat risky (backup your data first). That or make a new filesystem there, mount it somewhere and find a use for it that way. 19.2G might be just nice for a root partition, so the 50G could be /home.